# Is there any iOS library which provides networking as well as disk caching?

Tags: ios, caching, networking, disk

I just wanted to know that is there any library which provides networking as well as disk caching both for iOS 4 & above.
I know AFNetworking for networking & SDURLCache & AFCache for disk caching. But I want both support in one.
Any idea pleas help as I am new to iOS development.

Can I use AFNetwork with ARC enabled in iOS5. Will there be any issues for this?

I forgot to mention that I have read this option but as its going away I want to know whether there is any other option

Comment: if you need images I would take a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do need Images but with this I will need json & others too.

Comment: Personally I tend not to bother caching the JSON but it wouldn't be too hard to implement manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have read this option but  as its going away I want to know whether there is any other option

Answer (score 0):

Could [RestKit](http://restkit.org) be of any help? It let's you integrate stuff online to CoreData.